Why is focus lost when the same tab is opend twice via vba
I have a small vab script that opens a new tab in firefox for a specific site and inputs some data there. I have to do this over and over and noticed that each second time the tab is opened, the focus got lost - and it is really exactly each second time.
I wonder if this is a problem with vba or with firefox and what could be done to avoid this. For the moment I just use one more vba line to set the focus to the newly opened tab, but I do not understand where the issue occurs in the first place.
You can test this with the following vba code:
Sub Test_Firefox()

    'Shell """C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"" -safe-mode"

    Shell """C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"" -new-tab www.google.de"
    Shell """C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"" -new-tab www.google.de"
    'Shell """C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"" -new-tab www.google.de"

End Sub

Opening the tab once or three times, the focus is in the search of google, but opening it two times the focus is lost and I can not tell where it is.
I tried firefox in safe mode, different firefox versions (ESR and release) and two laptops (but all with Microsoft 365).

For me it happens with the 4th one. And I believe it is not a VBA issue. It is more with how Firefox handles it.
Try giving Firefox sometime to handle the commands. Something like this. This will put the foucs on the Google Search Box everytime.
Option Explicit

Sub Test_Firefox()
    Shell """C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"" -new-tab www.google.de"
    Wait 1 '<~~ Wait for 1 second
    Shell """C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"" -new-tab www.google.de"
    Wait 1
    Shell """C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"" -new-tab www.google.de"
    Wait 1
    Shell """C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"" -new-tab www.google.de"
    Wait 1
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub

I would also recommend not using this method. Use the Selenium WebDriver for Firefox. That is more reliable. One more thing... Your code would fail if the user installed Firefox using Microsoft Store and not online/offline installer. In such a case there will be no FireFox.Exe at C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox.
